# node uploading file $http.post from angularjs has undefined req.body

Tags: node.js, angularjs-http

I'm building a file upload functionality with my angularjs app that would upload a file to my node api that will ftp to a cdn server. Right now I'm stuck with just getting hte file. I tried using multer but I'm  not sure how to prevent the save to redirect to an ftp.

Anyway, this is my code withoout multer

```
 <input type="file" multiple  file-model="fileRepo"/>


myApp.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
        return {
           restrict: 'A',
           link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
              element.bind('change', function(){
                $parse(attrs.fileModel).assign(scope,element[0].files)
                scope.$apply();
              });
           }
        };
     }]);
```

///controller///

```
$scope.saveFile = function(){
        var fd=new FormData();
        angular.forEach($scope.fileRepo,function(file){
            fd.append('file',file);
        });

        $scope.newFile.files = fd;

        FileService.uploadFile($scope.newFile)
.....
```

/// fileservice ///

```
uploadFile: function(file){
           var deferred = $q.defer();

var uploadUrl = '/api/file/ftp/new';
                var requestFileUpload = {
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: uploadUrl,
                        data: file.files
                    }
                var requestFileUploadConfig = {
                    transformRequest: angular.identity,
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
                }
                $http.post(uploadUrl, file.files, requestFileUploadConfig)
                    .then(function(){
                     })
```

/// node part ///

```
router.post('/ftp/new',  function(req, res) {
        console.log('file is ' + JSON.stringify(req.body));
    });
```

Comment: which html parser are you using? busboy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use an HTML parser you are not going to be able to catch the file just by reading the request.

I'd recommend use [busboy](https://github.com/mscdex/busboy) and [connect-busboy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-busboy) then you are going to be able to read your file, this a small example:

```
req.pipe(req.busboy);
req.busboy.on('file',function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, contentType){
    // get data 
    file.on('data',function(data){

    }).on('end', function(){

    });
});


req.busboy.on('field',function(fieldname, val){
    req.body[fieldname] = val;
});

req.busboy.on('finish', function() {
    // save file here
});
```

Comment: i see. i thought i can just read the file without a parser. would you recommend multer? if not, does busboy have a way to go straight and ftp the file to a server?

Comment: I haven't use multer but check it out, my recommendation is based on my experience but you can use the one you like the most, I'm not sure about uploading directly to a ftp I haven't tried that yet, however a parse will do the trick to resolve the issue posted in your question.

Comment: you're right. btw, does busboy just automatically just save the file to a destination folder? if that's the case how do i grab it so i can ftp it? if you know.

Comment: you'll have to save it by yourself, basically, what you are getting is a buffer